# How can I view the max wattage of my usbcpd port of my laptop?

Tags: windows, usb, io, usb-pd

I have a Lenovo laptop with one of the USB C 3.2 gen 2 ports labeled as USB-PD, and I'm wondering what it is rated for. Based on some Googling it seems that USB 3.1 PD ports support up to 240 watts, but I'm not sure what that port is. There are no port labels regarding speed. Is there some software that can scan the USB ports and give me the specs of each one?

Here is a screenshot of device manager if needed:

[image: Device manager screenshot]

Comment: refer to the laptop technical datasheet

Comment: It says USB 3.2 gen 2 however cause USB has been renamed so much I'm not sure how that matches up with PD wattage, which is why I asked for software that does that can check the ports. Sorry I should have probably said USB 3.2 gen 2 in my question

Comment: edit your question if you like

Comment: USB 3.2 gen 2 tells you the speed of data transfers from the port, it tells you nothing about the power capabilities: https://www.theverge.com/circuitbreaker/2019/2/27/18243425/usb-3-2-standard-names-connectivity-cables-innovators-forum

Comment: What do you mean "max wattage"? Do you mean what kind of power will be taken  by your laptop if a USB-C charger is plugged into USB-C port, or how much power you might expect FROM this port to some USB device?

Answer (score 0):

Picking a [Lenovo laptop at random](https://www.lenovo.com/gb/en/p/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpadz/thinkpad-z13-(13-inch-amd)/21d2cto1wwgb2) and looking at the specifications page:

> #### AC Adapter / Power Supply
>
> 65W USB-C Slim 3pin AC Adapter - UK

So it is safe to say that the USB C port supports at least 65W PD.

You should look at your manufacturer support pages and manual to determine what adaptors are supported.

You might be able to use a program such as [Battery Information View](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/battery_information_view.html) to see how fast your battery is charging, but bear in mind that most of the time your laptop will be both charging and using the power to actually work so you will only see half the drain from the adaptor.

If you want to know how much power is actually being taken then you will need a USB power meter of some kind that takes in power from your adaptor and can pass it through to your laptop.  Something like this [USB power tester](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0B99Z2GJK/ref=emc_b_5_mob_i)

As far as I know there is no way to "read" a port to find out what it supports. Everything is down to the battery charging circuitry to accept power and that circuitry is a black box that just takes in power and either charges the battery or powers the laptop.

Comment: USB-C isn't the default charging port of my laptop, it is Lenovo's own charging port, no clue what it is. It charges through that at 235 watts. I only have a 100-watt USB-C charger, which is why I can't measure the power input, and I'm not buying one just to test, the main reason for the question is to know if it can even support that.

Comment: @SpaceFlier  And that is why I said you need to look at the laptop manual or specifications. You've not told us what your laptop is apart from "lenovo" so we have no way to get concrete information. As I say there's no way to "read" the port except for in information given by the manufacturer. If your power brick is 240W then a 100W PD charger might well charge your laptop when you aren't doing demanding things like gaming, but beyond that we cannot say.